# Widget update not working properly

Tags: android, timer, widget, timertask, onupdate

I have a `widget` which I am updating from my application. The `widget` is showing a live game score. When there is an update from the server, `Widget` is updated but it blinks between the previous update and the current update. Like if the score was `12-0`, and now it is `15-0`, The widget shows `15-0, 12-0, 15-0, 12-0` and so on. Please tell me where am I going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Here's the code for the widget

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public String team1name="";
    public String team2name="";
    public String team1score="0";
    public String team2score="0";
    public String player1;
    public String player2;
    public String nonStriker;
    public String role1;
    public String role2;


            public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {
                super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
                final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
                Log.e(MyWidgetProvider.class.toString(), "Onupdate called for " + this);
                for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                    int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
                  RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName (), R.layout.widget_layout);                   
                  ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
                  appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
            }

        }
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                if (extras == null) {
                  return;
                }
                team1name = extras.getString("team1name");
                team2name = extras.getString("team2name");
                team1score = extras.getString("team1score");
                team2score=extras.getString("team2score");
                player1=extras.getString("player1");
                player2=extras.getString("player2");
                nonStriker=extras.getString("nonStriker");
                role1=extras.getString("role1");
                role2=extras.getString("role2");


                team1name=getAcronym(team1name,context);
                team2name=getAcronym(team2name,context);
                RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);


                      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.team1name, team1name);
                      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.team2name, team2name);
                      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.team1score, team1score);  
                      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.team2score, team2score); 
                        if(role1!=null && role1.equalsIgnoreCase("batsman")) {                    
                      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.batsman1, player1);
                        }else if(role1!=null && role1.equalsIgnoreCase("bowler")) {
                            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.bowler, player1);                          
                        }

                        if(role2!=null && role2.equalsIgnoreCase("batsman")) {                    
                              remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.batsman1, player2);
                                }else if(role2!=null && role2.equalsIgnoreCase("bowler")) {
                                    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.bowler, player2);                          
                                }
                      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.nonStriker, nonStriker);

                      Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                      PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
                      in = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("My Package name");
                      in.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0 /* no requestCode */, in, 0 /* no flags */);
                      remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layout, pendingIntent);

                        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);  
                        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(cn, remoteViews);

            }

            String getAcronym(String teamName,Context context){

                if(teamName==null){
                    return "";
                }
                if(teamName.equals("Australia")){
                    teamName="AUS"; 
                }
                else if(teamName.equals("Pakistan")){
                    teamName="PAK";
                }
                else if(teamName.equals("India")){
                    teamName="IND";
                }
                else if(teamName.equals("England")){
                    teamName="ENG"; 
                }   
                else if(teamName.equals("Sri Lanka")){
                    teamName="SL";
                }   
                else if(teamName.equals("South Africa")){
                    teamName="RSA";
                }
                else if(teamName.equals("West Indies")){
                    teamName="WI";
                }
                else if(teamName.equalsIgnoreCase("New Zealand")){
                    teamName="NZ";
                }
                else if(teamName.equals("Zimbabwe")){
                    teamName="ZIM";
                }
                else if(teamName.equals("Ireland")){
                    teamName="IRE";
                }               else if(teamName.equals("Afghanistan")){
                    teamName="AFG";
                }
                return teamName;
            }           

} 

and Here's the code from the application which is sending the broadcast.

                if(GameCentre){
                    watchFromHome.setText("Watch From Home");
                    intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction("android.intent.action.RUN");
                        intent.putExtra("team1name", data.get( "vHomeDisplayName") .get( position ));
                        intent.putExtra("team2name", data.get( "vAwayDisplayName") .get( position ));
                        intent.putExtra("team1score", data.get( "vSummary1") .get( position ));
                        intent.putExtra("team2score", data.get( "vSummary2") .get( position ));
                        intent.putExtra("player1", data.get( "vPlayerLastName1" ).get( position ));
                        intent.putExtra("player2", data.get( "vPlayerLastName2" ).get( position ));
                        intent.putExtra("nonStriker", data.get( "vNonStrikerLastName" ).get( position ));
                        intent.putExtra("role1", data.get( "vRole1" ).get( position ));
                        intent.putExtra("role2", data.get( "vRole2" ).get( position ));


                    watchFromHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                        public void onClick(View v){
                            startTimer=true;
                            PlayUpActivity.context.sendBroadcast(intent);                                                   
                        }
                    });
                    if(isLiveMatch){
                        timer = new Timer();
                        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                            public void run() {

                                    intent.putExtra("team1name", data.get( "vHomeDisplayName") .get( position ));
                                    intent.putExtra("team2name", data.get( "vAwayDisplayName") .get( position ));
                                    intent.putExtra("team1score", data.get( "vSummary1") .get( position ));
                                    intent.putExtra("team2score", data.get( "vSummary2") .get( position ));
                                    intent.putExtra("player1", data.get( "vPlayerLastName1" ).get( position ));
                                    intent.putExtra("player2", data.get( "vPlayerLastName2" ).get( position ));
                                    intent.putExtra("nonStriker", data.get( "vNonStrikerLastName" ).get( position ));
                                    intent.putExtra("role1", data.get( "vRole1" ).get( position ));
                                    intent.putExtra("role2", data.get( "vRole2" ).get( position ));
                                    PlayUpActivity.context.sendBroadcast(intent);   
    //                          }
                            }
                        }, 0, 5000);
                    }
                }
```